# why is $\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ referred to as the "p-part"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group. I read that *$G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p$ is the $p$-part* (my definition is it is the collection elements with $p$th power order).

How does one see this? I've written my thoughts, but I'd be happy for a more conceptual suggestion.

**Edit: a. it seems that $G$ needs to be torsion, b. my argument doesn't work.**

My thoughts have two parts:

1. We have ses
   $$M^p \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/M^p $$
   tensoring with $\otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ yields an isomoprhism between the first  ($p$-part) and second term. Here I thought a $p$-part free group $\otimes\mathbb{Z}_p$ would be trivial, but this is false as commented.
2. If $G$ is a $p$-group, then $G \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p = G$? It seems to me that I can define a map $$G \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow  G$$
   By $(g,p^nu) \mapsto p^ng$, for $u$ a unit. This seems to be injective: $p^ng=e$ iff $o(g)|n$, iff $(g,p^n)=(e,1)$.

Comment: A torsion abelian group? Otherwise $\Bbb Z\otimes\Bbb Z_p\cong\Bbb Z_p$, for instance. (Also should mention $\Bbb Z_p$ is the $p$-adics not the integers mod $p$.)

Comment: Thanks, edited, but now I am more confused the statement.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian and torsion then tensoring with $p$-adic integers gives that $G\to G\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}_p$ is surjective with kernel the elements of order coprime with $p$, whence $G\cong \bigoplus_p G\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}_p$. You can tensor with $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}=(\Bbb{Z}-(p))^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see 1. why the first map is surjective 2. You get the isomoprhism: should the codomain be a product $\prod_p G \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ for the map you defined?